# Programming Languages Grammar Ambiguity

Tags: formal-grammars, programming-languages, ambiguity

I don't know if it is the right site to ask  this. But we're studying about ambiguities of grammar. Including left most derivation and right most derivation. We are given the problem:

```
E -> E * E | E + E | N
N -> 0N | 1N |
Output: 0110 + 110 * 01111
```

My question is, is there a shortest way to attain that output? Because in my leftmost and rightmost derivation it took 7 lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a shortest way?" The length of any derivation is a natural number and any set of natural numbers has a unique smallest element. So the answer to the literal question is "Yes, there is a shortest way." What are you actually looking for?

Comment: Did you mean to ask: "What is the best known time complexity for determining whether a Grammar is ambiguous?"

Comment: Your grammar won't generate any strings of terminals unless you add some productions like $N\rightarrow 0\mid 1$.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the grammar is ambiguous.

There are two ways of producing the result $0110 + 110 \ast 01111$:
The one for $(0110 + 110) \ast 01111$ and the other for $(0110 + 110) \ast 01111$.
Try them both.

---

As for your question,

> Is there a shortest way to attain that output? Because in my leftmost and rightmost derivation it took 7 lines.

"Number of Lines" sounds quite vague.